# Extracting list of filenames from Github page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm making a program in python that scans my friend and myself's GitHub page and displays all the names of the files uploaded. I have managed to get it to do this. All the names of the files are under the  tag. The problem is there is other random text like "Add files via upload" that are under the  tag. I do not want these to show up. Any help would be appreciated. Kind regards. Eric

I've tried string stripping when printing the final result but that still wont work.

Here is my code:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml
import re
import time
import os
import webbrowser
import re

def webscrape():
    res = requests.get('https://github.com/Dukesan7/jerichson')
    type(res)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    type(soup)
    file = soup.select('a')
    file[1].getText()
    time.sleep(1)
    files = str(file)
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    files = re.sub(clean, '', files)
    print (files)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("1. Main Menu: 1")
    print ("2. exit?: 2")
    op = input (":")
    if op == "2":
        exit()
    else:
        MainMenu()
```

Comment: Did you want to include or exclude folders? e.g. Google2

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

res = requests.get('https://github.com/Dukesan7/jerichson')    
soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')   
file = soup.find_all('a',class_="js-navigation-open")
for i in file:
    if '.' in i.text:
        print(i.text)
```

Provides this output:

```
21s.py
BVVVVV.exe
Calling Casino.py
Game Download Link.txt
Homework.py
Password Username System.py
Puzzle.txt
StopWatch.py
Voting ligitimacy system.py
Vowl counter.py
agenotage.py
coin.py
dice.py
explorer reset.bat
name and age dukesan.py
notification.pyw
reminder.py
win 21 game.py
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that this doesn't include folder names (not sure if OP wants them included or not). Also this would exclude any filename that doesn't contain a period (which can happen).

Comment: Indeed; since OP didn't indicate his desired output, I figured this is close enough and, if necessary, he can modify the code to suit his needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Inspector in your browser, you can try to find a class and/or tag common to all the file/folder names. I've found that they're all inside a `td` element with class `content`, which has a `tr` element with class `js-navigation-item` as parent:

[image: inspector]

Hence you can use the following selector in BeautifulSoup: `tr.js-navigation-item > td.content`

Note that you can simply extract the text of an HTML element with the syntax `elem.text`. Using Regex is not suited for stripping HTML tags.

Working implementation:

```
res = requests.get('https://github.com/Dukesan7/jerichson')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
files_list = soup.select('tr.js-navigation-item > td.content')
files_list_text = [f.text.strip() for f in files_list]
print(files_list_text)
```

Output:

```
['Google2', 'Maths Game', 'OpenMinecraft', '21s.py', 'BVVVVV.exe', 'Calling Casino.py', 'Game Download Link.txt', 'Homework.py', 'Password Username System.py', 'Puzzle.txt', 'StopWatch.py', 'Voting ligitimacy system.py', 'Vowl counter.py', 'agenotage.py', 'coin.py', 'dice.py', 'explorer reset.bat', 'name and age dukesan.py', 'notification.pyw', 'privilege_escalation', 'reminder.py', 'win 21 game.py']
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just wondering if you could tell me what this line does exactly so I can better understand it. Thanks
    

files_list = soup.select('tr.js-navigation-item > td.content')

Comment: `td.content` means `td` element with class `content`. Similarly `tr.js-navigation-item` means `tr` element with class `js-navigation`. The `element1 > element2 ` syntax means, only select `element1` if it is contained by `element2`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator for

Comment: oh ok. But when I inspect the page there I cant see tr anywhere near the content?

Comment: Inspect the filename specifically to find the element. Or check the page source with Ctrl+U and search for `tr` with Ctrl+F. See the image I added in my answer.